# App clip push notifications after full app install

Tags: ios, apple-appclips

Apple App Clips allow for a quick iOS experience without needing a download from the App Store. These App Clips allow for ephemeral notifications for up to 8 hours after launch. In the app clips, developers have the opportunity to present a download banner for the full app. When the full app is downloaded, it replaces the App Clip.

My question is: what happens to the ephemeral notification authorization if the full app is installed during this 8-hour window? Can the full app still receive notifications for the remainder of this period? Or does the full app need to ask for permissions for notifications? How does this work?